# Copy the files from folders recursively with wildcard characters (folder path has wildcard characters)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows

Good day.

I have to copy  all the  files in folders (including sub folders) to other shared drive location for backup the data. The challenge, which I am facing is folder path with wildcard characters.

For example,

The folder structure is like below

> D:/Folder1/Folder11/Folder111
>
> D:/Folder2/Folder222/Folder222222
>
> D:/Folder3/Folder333333/Folder3333333

I am looking for the input format should be "D:/Folder?/Folder*/Folder*". So that it has to loop according to the wildcard character patterns.

Can you please help me.

Regards,

Chandra

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Do you mean that the input should be a regular expression? In that case, can you just traverse your folder structure recursively, and apply the regex to each file path to look for matches, then copy the file if it matches?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave, thanks for comment. the input I want to give from my UI is "D:/Folder?/Folder*/Folder*". Then the files from these matched folders should be copied to shared drive for backup.

Comment: Sorry, judging by the answers you've already had, I think you need to edit your question to clarify this. Are you saying that the only things that change are the numbers in your example? Further will they always be numbers, or could they be other characters? Does the `?` in your example mean '0 or 1' and does the `*` mean '1 or more'? Or something different? Are the directories always three levels deep, or could that vary too?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave, ? refers one character and * refers 1 or more. The folders can be deeper. But the requirement is to file the folder pattern and copy the files. Thanks

Comment: @Chanda - the `*` usually refers to zero or more. You can use the combination `?*` to change the meaning to one or more.

Comment: @Chandra - Are you asking for only the files in the folders that match `"D:\Folder?\Folder*\Folder*"` to be copied? Or are you also asking for the files that match `"D:\"`, `"D:\Folder?"`, `"D:\Folder?\Folder*"`, & `"D:\Folder?\Folder*\Folder*"` to be copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this with a simple `RegularExpression`. I've created an example which does the job for you.

The `RegEx` string is quite easy: `[A-Z]:\\Folder[0-9]{1}\\Folder[0-9]{2}\\Folder[0-9]{3}`

```
[A-Z]:\\Folder[0-9]{1}\\Folder[0-9]{2}\\Folder[0-9]{3}
-----         --------        --------        --------
Drive         1x digit        2x digit        3x digit
```

See the sample at [regexr](http://regexr.com/3ceiv).

**EDIT:**

```
//using System.IO;

public void CopyMatching(string drive)
{
    try
    {
        var backuplocation = ""; //the path where you wanna copy your files to
        var regex = new Regex(@"[A-Z]:\\Folder[0-9]{1}\\Folder[0-9]{2}\\Folder[0-9]{3}");
        var directories = new List<string>();
        foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(drive))
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(directory))
            {
                directories.Add(directory);
            }
        }
        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            DirectoryCopy(directory, backuplocation, true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

And **DirectoryCopy**:

```
public void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{
    // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
    // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }

    // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
    }

    // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
    if (copySubDirs)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have to copy all the files from the matched folders. Folder name format is not fixed. Here the folder name could changes like  D:/Folder1/Folder11/Folder111

D:/Folder2/Folder222/Folder2222

D:/Folder3/Folder333333/Folder3333333. In this case I can't use regex. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Chandra your question currently does only ask for a way getting all the folders that match a pattern. for this purpose you have to ask a new question.

Comment: @cramopy - I read the question as wanting to copy the files. I think you've possibly only answered half the question. I also think you need to show how this applies to the full question.

Comment: @Enigmativity added sample

Answer (score -1):

```
IEnumerable<string> getMatchingSubDir(string dirPath, string pattern)
{
   List<string> matchingFolders = new List<string>();
   DirectoryInfo myDir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
   foreach (var subDir in myDir.GetDirectories(pattern))
   {
       matchingFolders.AddRange(getMatchingSubDir(subDir.FullName, pattern));
   }
   return matchingFolders;
}
```

Then this call will return you a list of all folders matching your pattern:

```
getMatchingSubDir("D:\\", "Folder*");
```

Comment: This should be `subDir.FullName`, not `subDir.FullPath`.